# how to open a pop-up (usercontrol) from another usercontrol in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

The show and `showDialog` method are not showing by IntelliSense, and if typed explicitly giving me a compile-time error, this method `Edit()` has the same signature as Action delegate if in case you wanted to know

```
private RelayCommand editCommand;

public RelayCommand EditCommand
{
    get { return editCommand; }
    set { editCommand = value; }
}

public void Edit()
{
    EditView editView = new EditView();
    editView.Show
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wpf: How popup a usercontrol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719977/wpf-how-popup-a-usercontrol)

Comment: UserControl do not have Show() or ShowDialog().

Comment: You'd have to put the UserControl inside a Window and call Show() on that Window.